# Matching phone numbers within a vCard or CSV

Tags: csv, outlook, comparison, whatsapp, vcard

I have an iPhone with Whatsapp, and a Windows PC with Outlook 2016 that also runs iCloud sync, to sync Outlook contacts with iCloud.

Somehow, phone numbers from one contact have been copied over to other contacts with similar names (not necessarily the same name, just similar). I'm not sure how many contacts have been affected, or even if it's just the phone number field.

I would assume iCloud sync, Outlook or Whatsapp has screwed this up, I'm not sure which.

My idea is to compare phone numbers within an exported vCard or CSV file, and see which match. Hopefully there aren't too many and can be corrected manually.

I need suggestions for a vCard or CSV comparison program or any other ideas for sorting this out.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office 2016 provides the "Spreadsheet Compare 2016" tool (you can find it in Windows Start Menu). It can compare Excel files. So, you can open your CSV files in Excel, save them as .xlsx and then compare using the mentioned tool. Also, you can use just the Excel itself to compare two tables by selected columns (VLOOKUP function can be helpul).

One more way is to use the [Find Duplicate Outlook Contacts](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/OutlookContactsMarkDuplicates) tool and select the required phone numbers as fields to compare. This tool will flag or assign categories to the "duplicates" found.